# Pandas groupby aggregation multiple sums

Tags: python, pandas

Newbie question.  I would like to calculate a dataframe column using two summed up columns like so:

```
grouped_columns = df1.groupby(['Parent1', 'Parent2']).agg(Attr_fac = ('Exposure1', 'sum') / ('Exposure2', 'sum'))
```

keep getting TypeError: Unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'tuple' and 'tuple'

Exposure1, and Exposure2 are numeric columns being read in from excel file.   Please help, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't really do `('Exposure1', 'sum') / ('Exposure2', 'sum')` hence the error. You can try:

```
grouped_columns = (df1.groupby(['Parent1', 'Parent2'])
                      [['Exposure1','Exposure2']].sum()
                      .assign(Attr_fac=lambda x: x['Exposure1']/x['Exposure2'])
                  )
```

Or `groupby().apply()`:

```
grouped_columns = (df1.groupby(['Parent1', 'Parent2'])
                      .apply(lmabda x: x['Exposure1'].sum()/x['Exposure2'].sum())
                  )
```

Answer (score 0):

This is culprit `('Exposure1', 'sum') / ('Exposure2', 'sum')`.

In this `('Exposure1', 'sum')` is a tuple and `('Exposure2', 'sum')` is another tuple. And `/` operation is not defined for tuple. Please explain with the sample DataFrame what you are trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I'm trying to divide the summed up value of Exposure1 by the summed up value of Exposure2.
I can get the sum value of Exposure1 with: grouped_columns = df1.groupby(['Parent1', 'Parent2']).agg(Attr_fac = ('Exposure1', 'sum')). I want to add additional sum columns (Not like this one).